# NGINX with certbot forwarding https url request to api and dockerized react app

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, certbot

I'm running NGINX on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionix in a Digital Ocean Droplet. I have a dockerized React App which I can successfully reach and use with a dockerized Flask/Quart App when using http. The React App can be reached at example:8000 and the Quart at example:9000. The 2 communicate fine.

Now when setting up https using NGINX and the commonly used certbot method (thank you for the tutorial: [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04)) I get errors that don't completely tell me what is going on.

After completing the tutorial and successfully displaying the html file in /var/www/example/index.html at https://www.example.com, I try https://www.example.com/app for the React app that I can reach on http 8000 and the /api site that I can reach on http 9000 with a standard doc page.

The React App shows the title as expected in the browser tab but there is nothing displayed. Only 404 errors saying 'failed to load resource' from css chunks.

The API fails also with failed to load resource.

The only NGINX configuration changed based on research found so far is the following:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example
server {

    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /app {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
 }
 server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 } # managed by Certbot


 if ($host = example.com) {
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Also have tried to add / to both api and app (location /app/, /api/) and the result changes but still errors. In this case it is still the 404 for api but it says URI doesn't exist. In the case of the react app it gives syntax errors based on the css it is reading.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.